# How to make live ios app with paypal MPL

Tags: ios, paypal

I am using paypal MPL library in my application that is working fine in sandbox mode and I am using Application-id  APP-80W284485P519543T for testing mode .

From the application the customer can make payment to one reciepient that is static and payment will go to my client account .

Now i want  to make my app live and i need live AppId for Paypal MPL .
Acccording to developer docs i need to create App in paypal developer site which i already did but i only get client id and secret id there which i don't need because i have used MPL library.

So , I just want to know that from where i can get Appid for paypal MPL.

should i need to create App again from client account.

I  didn't upload any app using paypal.
any help or suggestion will be helpfull.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MPL uses Classic App ID, you need to create Classic App instead of Rest App.

1. Log in to the PayPal Developer website using the credentials of the PayPal account registered to the application owner.
   Note that the PayPal account associated with the application must be a verified Premier or verified Business account.
2. Click Applications on the nav bar to access the My Applications page.
3. Click Create and Manage Classic API Apps link at the bottom of the page to access the My Applications page.
   (Alternately, you can go directly to the My Applications page by navigating to the My Apps page on the Developer Portal.)
4. Click New App on the left nav bar to access the App Information form.
5. Complete the form and click the Submit App button.To ensure the fastest possible application review, supply as much information as possible when completing the submittal form.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/goingLive/#register

Comment: Thanks ,It sounds very helpfull let me try once.

Comment: i am unable to login with my developer paypal account here should i need live paypal acvcount here

Comment: yes, you need to login into PayPal Developer Portal using your Live PayPal account

Comment: It is asking me so many details including Some Testing information like
" Ad Hoc files required for mobile app submissions)"  Do you have any idea on that what can i upload here